# How to refresh the current page after selecting an item in ListPicker

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listpicker

I'd like to know how to refresh the current page with

`heNavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(NavigationService.Source + "?Refresh=true", UriKind.Relative));`

after i pick an element in the ListPicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using MVVM Light for Windows Phone. In that case, you should catch the event in your page and then trigger a command on your ViewModel.

Example:

**Code-behind of the page**

```
private void Listbox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ViewModelClass vm = this.DataContext as ViewMoedlClass;
    if (vm != null)
    {
        vm.RefreshCommand.Execute();
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class ViewModelClass
{
    public ViewModelClass
    {
        this.RefreshCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(NavigationService.Source + "?Refresh=true", UriKind.Relative));
        }   
    }

    public RelayCommand RefreshCommand { get; set;}

}
```

**Xaml**

```
<ListBox SelectionChanged="Listbox_SelectionChanged" />
```

In theory you shouldn't have to do this in your code-behind and you would bind your Command from the ViewModel directly to the SelectionChanged-event, but this is not (directly) possible in Windows Phone. If you want to go this route you can take a look at EventToCommand. This page explains the steps in more detail: http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/how-to-bind-a-windows-phone-control-event-to-a-command-using-mvvm-light

Comment: Really thank you for the good answer, but you know a way without using MVVM?
Thank you for the patience (I'm noob)

Comment: In that case you can do it immediately in the event handler: NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(NavigationService.Source + "?Refresh=true", UriKind.Relative)); Just leave out the ViewModel class and put the code from the command directly inside the handler. What do you exactly mean by "Refreshing the current page"?

Comment: For refresh i mean exactly this NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(NavigationService.Source + "?Refresh=true", UriKind.Relative)),
but when i open the page with the LispPicker i have an error System.NullReferenceException

this is the code

private void lpkVoti_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(NavigationService.Source + "?Refresh=true", UriKind.Relative));
            
        }

Comment: Does the exception occur inside the event handler or after that? If inside, which object has a null reference? The NavigationService or the Source property of the NavigationService?

Comment: I just tried this out in a sample app and it seems to work. You can access the xaml here: http://pastebin.com/821NSVac and the code here: http://pastebin.com/7tb0NJEe Could you try this and see if it works and is any different from what you have?

Comment: it is the same if i have a ListPicker and you a ListBox?

Comment: It should be. What ListPicker are you using? (ListPicker is not a native control for Windows Phone).

Comment: silverlight toolkit.

I think that the problem is that in the moment i go in the page where is palced the ListPicker, immediatly i got the Exception.. Not when i change his value. Ideas?

Comment: I think I know where the problem probably is. When you load the items into your listpicker, the navigation service is not yet properly initialized. But on loading the items, the SelectionChanged event is already fired (since it goes from no selection to something selected), hence a NullReferenceException on the navigationservice. You could do a null-check before accessing the NavigationService. In case it's null, the event was fired because of initialization, otherwise it was because you selected a different value. So something like this: if (NavigationService != null) { // do the navigation }

Comment: We almost got it :D Now the problem is that i have a continuosly refresh of that page, is like that lpkVoti_SelectionChanged is continuosly called..

Comment: Yes, probably because you are reassigning the value to the selecteditem, thus retriggering the event. You need to find a way to no trigger the event when you reassign the value or not trigger the navigation when you know the event was caused by the reassignment. Two routes here: remove the handler just before reassigning the selected value and attaching it afterwards. The other method: apart from the null check, do another to see whether the addeditem is the value you just reassigned (you can find the addeditem in the eventargs)

Comment: Got it! in lpkVoti_SelectionChanged() i call the method that i putted in the cunstructor, before i needed to refresh the page for see the effect but now it work perfercly :D
Thank you for the patience and the good answers!

Answer (score -1):

set your autopostback to true, sample:

```
  <asp:DropDownList  OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropDown_indexChange" ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
```

Comment: The question is not about asp.net but about windows phone / xaml